# Databricks SQL doesn't seem to support SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I've created some hive tables using a JDBC in a python notebook on Databricks. This was on Data Science and Engineering UI. I'm able to query the tables in a Databricks Notebook and user direct SQL with the magic command %

When switching to Databricks SQL UI, I'm still able to see the tables in Hive metastore explorer. However I'm not able to read the data. A very clear message says that only csv, parquet and so are supported.

Even though, I found this surprising, since I can use the data on DS and Engineering UI why it's not the case on Databricks SQL? Is there any solution to overcome that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Nov 2023: Databricks SQL now supports [query federation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/query-federation/index.html) that allows to connect to different databases

Yes, it's a known limitation that Databricks SQL right now supports only file-based formats.  As I remember it's related to a security model, plus the fact that DBSQL is using Photon under the hood where JDBC integration could be not so performant.  You may reach your solution architect or customer success engineer to get information on if it will be supported in the future.

The current workaround would be only to have a job that will periodically read all data from database via JDBC and dump into Delta table - it could be even more performant compared to JDBC, the only issue is the freshness of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can import a Hive table from cloud storage into Databricks using an external table and query it using Databricks SQL.

**Step 1:** Show the CREATE TABLE statement

Issue a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` command on your Hive command line to see the statement that created the table.

Refer below example:

```
hive> SHOW CREATE TABLE wikicc;
OK
CREATE  TABLE `wikicc`(
  `country` string,
  `count` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/user/hive/warehouse/wikicc'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'totalSize'='2335',
  'numRows'='240',
  'rawDataSize'='2095',
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true',
  'numFiles'='1',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1418173653')
```

**Step 2:** Issue a CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE statement

If the statement that is returned uses a **CREATE TABLE** command, copy the statement and replace **CREATE TABLE with CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE**.

- EXTERNAL ensures that Spark SQL does not delete your data if you drop the table.
- You can omit the TBLPROPERTIES field.

`DROP TABLE wikicc`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `wikicc`(
  `country` string,
  `count` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/user/hive/warehouse/wikicc'
```

Step 3: Issue SQL commands on your data

`SELECT * FROM wikicc`

Source: https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/hive-tables.html

Comment: Question is about access data in external databases via JDBC...

Comment: Tried to provide a alternative solution as I think what OP is asking isn't possible.

Comment: thanks. I have 2 follow up questions. How to access Hive command line, I couldn't find any path to there? secondly I see the doc you refer to mentioning creating a table from cloud storage, is it applicable to MS SQL tables? I couldn't check myself as long as I couldn't access the Hive CLI

Comment: AFAIK there is no Hive command line available in databricks. The doc isn't applicable to SQL table therefore you need to first create the external table in storage account and then access it using databricks SQL.

Comment: This is the limitation and therefore you can opt for this given workaround.